# Auto insert a closing brace putting the cursor between the braces in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins

I have found some threads on this but they are three years old. Does anyone have a plugin to recommend for Vim, so that when I type `{`,
it will do:

```
{
::cursor here::
}
```

Another helpful thing would be to have

```
if(::cursor here::)
```

after typing `if`.

Comment: I am curious about that plugin (preferably universal ). For now I used to type `{<Enter>}<^O>O` to get same effect

Comment: What does this have to do with Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) plugin. It is very customizable. There is a excellent [screen-cast](http://vimeo.com/3535418) showing the plugin in action.

For example in C with snipMate plugin.

```
if<Tab>

would produce:

if (::cursor:1::) {
    ::cursor:2::
}
```

First <Tab> would leave the cursor at ::cursor:1:: and second <Tab> would take you to ::cursor:2::.

There should be some thing similar for bash scripts in snipMate, if not it is very simple to add one.

Comment: Very useful.. Seems to have some problems though setting up a { trigger like above (without requiring a for statement or the like) Have you had any luck doing that or do you just go with the provided snippets?

Comment: I usually use the default ones. But I did try adding a snippet for "{", it did work. I added this snippet http://vim.pastey.net/132128 to ~/.vim/snippets/sh.snippets (Shell scripting snippets).

Answer (score 3):

I use [delimiteMate.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754).  It handles this in a configurable and non annoying way.

Answer (score 1):

I use following code (php-templates):

```
function! EatChar()
    let l:char=getchar(0)
    return ''
endfunction

inoreabbrev function_ function <ESC>maa()<CR>{<CR><CR>}<ESC>`aa<C-O>:call EatChar()<CR>
inoreabbrev if_ if (<ESC>maa)<CR>{<CR><CR>}<ESC>`aa<C-O>:call EatChar()<CR>
inoreabbrev ifelse_ if (<ESC>maa)<CR>{<CR><CR>}<CR>else<CR>{<CR><CR>}<ESC>`aa<C-O>:call EatChar()<CR>
inoreabbrev for_ for (<ESC>maa; ; )<CR>{<CR><CR>}<ESC>`aa<C-O>:call EatChar()<CR>
inoreabbrev foreach_ foreach (<ESC>maa as $key=>$value)<CR>{<CR><CR>}<ESC>`aa<C-O>:call EatChar()<CR>
inoreabbrev while_ while (<ESC>maa)<CR>{<CR><CR>}<ESC>`aa<C-O>:call EatChar()<CR>
inoreabbrev <? <?php <ESC>maa ?><ESC>`aa<C-O>:call EatChar()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) shows a simple solution and has links to some that are more robust.

Here is part of the solution from that page:

```
inoremap {      {}<Left>
inoremap {<CR>  {<CR>}<Esc>O
inoremap {{     {
inoremap {}     {}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many plugins and ftplugins that does the job. Most of the time newers plugins are not better as they often reinvent the wheel without taking odd cases into account.

In the "old" stuff, I have:

- [My code bracketing system](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_bracketing_subsystem) that simplifies the definition of mappings aimed at inserting balanced pair of brackets-like characters.
- and [related functions](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_VimL_library) that aim at simplifying the task of defining evolved (*) code-snippets (typically the control statements). I have examples of use for [C++](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/cpp/trunk/ftplugin/c/c_snippets.vim).

(*) The expansion of mappings/abbreviations is prevented in comments/strings context, several surrounding forms of the C control-statements are provided, and a few stylistic options are also supported (in the case of the C control-statements; they are easy to transpose to other languages)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the full power of various text snippet plugins (or
do not want to figure out how to configure them to suit your needs)
and have only a couple simple templates, you can just create a mapping
for each of them. For instance:

```
:nmap <leader>b o{<cr>}<esc>O
```